# How to solve " TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple " when comparing tuples in two different lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples, typeerror, networkx

```
for x in no_dupes: #looks at tuple in list 
    if x != totallist[x]: #checks when a tuple in no_dupes is not in totallist 
        return "The graph violates the STC" #ends the function, because as soon as one tuple in no_dupes isn't in totallist, the graph violats the STC.
```

I want to compare all the tuples from one list (in the list no_dupes) with another list (totallist), in order to see whether a tuple of a list in no_dupes is **not** in totallist.

This is how no_dupes looks like

[image: img]

This is how totallist looks like

[image: img]

How the error looks like

[image: img]

How can this error be solved?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You can't index an item in a list with a tuple. A tuple can be used as a dictionary key.  Have you tried `x in totallist`?

Answer (score 0):

The Error is caused by the fact, that x is a tuple and you can not use a tuple as an index for the totallist. This has to be an integer.

The problem is avoided if you compare the tuples directly by looping through both list.

```
no_dupes = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
totallist = [(8,9), (7,8), (6,7), (5,6), (4,5), (3,4), (2,3), (1,2)]

for tup in no_dupes:
    found = False;
    for other_tup in totallist:
        if tup == other_tup:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        print "Tuple", str(tup), "was found"
    else:
        print "Tuple", str(tup), "was not found"
```

In this example the output is

```
Tuple (1, 2) was found
Tuple (3, 4) was found
Tuple (5, 6) was found
```